# Создание платной и бесплатной (урезаной) версии приложения.

Tags: android

Есть готовое приложение. Стоит задача сделать еще одну версию с урезанным функционалом.
Вижу 2 пути решения:

1. Сделать в конфиге флаг и потом в
       местах вызова урезаемого контента
       воткнуть проверки (не знаю
       компилятор уберет неиспользуемые
       ветвления или нет).
2. Создать в репозитории отдельную
       ветку и там уже реально выпилить
       урезанный функционал.

Подскажите какой из этих методов лучше подойдет или может быть есть иной подход.

Comment: Интересно, за что вопрос-то минусуют?

Comment: видимо по причине наличия слов "платной", "урезанной" и подсознательным протестом против того, что кто то хочет заработать денег.

Comment: наверное, эти люди работают исключительно на общественных началах  и при попытке начальства заикнуться об увеличении им зарплаты тут же грозятся уволиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор может убрать, а может и не убрать. Его задача сделать так, что бы поведение кода не поменялось от его манипуляций.
По факту, для этого обычно используют два способа. Первый называется `antenna` и на хабре есть [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107652/) по его (или антенна - это она?) поводу. В результате получается препроцессор, как в С/С++. Позволят изголяться над кодом в широких пределах.

Второй способ мне больше нравится и различные `ide` к нему относятся лучше. Суть в том, что платная функциональность выноситься в отдельные классы, а также пишутся "зеркальные классы" с тем же интерфейсом, но с пустыми реализациями. А потом любым способом правиться скрипт сборки (`ant|gradle`), что бы он для разных сборок использовал разные каталоги. Если в имя каталога включить имя сборки, то все ещё упрощается. К примеру, для платной версии (`Paid`) классы будут храниться в каталоге "`ContentPaid`", а для бесплатной (`Free`) - в "`ContentFree`".

Этот способ может помочь и в других случаях. Пусть, нужно создать приложение для отображения новостей с сайта. Понятно, что они будут отличаться способом скачивания, способом приведения к читаемому виду, но вот код для отображения, для хранения и поиска по новостям будет один и тот же. Поэтому код скачивания и обработки выноситься в отдельные классы, которые будут храниться в отдельных каталогах, по каталогу на сайт. Если нужно будет написать для  нового заказчика, то нужно будет только добавить пару классов.

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае для разных приложений будет нужен разный package ID.
Я бы рекомендовал использовать для билда двух приложений(лайт и фул) из одного исходного кода такую штуку, как ANT. 
Вот ссылка на статью с примером: [Using Ant in Android applications building automatization](http://www.enterra-inc.com/techzone/using_ant_android_applications_building/).

Answer (score 0):

Прогон proguard'ом с включённым shrinking'ом уберёт весь неиспользуемый код.

Answer (score 0):

Если флаг будет `final static` то компилятор уберет неиспользуемые ветвления.

Я у себя задачу решал так:

1. Устанавливал флаг `public final static boolean LITE=true/false;` и ветвился в коде
2. Создавал 2 стартовых Activity скажем, `mypackage.MyMainActivity` и `mypackage.lite.MyMainActivity`
3. Делал 2 манифеста с разными стартовыми активити, которые подставлял по мере необходимости.