# Две версии android-проекта

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Как лучше организовать работу в IDE для двух версий (paid и free) android-приложения? В итоге будут два разных package. Если создавать два отдельных проекта, то проблемно их синхронизировать. Как бы сделать одну кодовую базу? Кто и как решает подобную проблему?
(в гугле толкового ничего не нашел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Уже было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/223972/android-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)