# Изменения кода в бесплатной и платной версии приложения одновременно

Tags: android

Есть приложение N, у него есть две версии - платная и бесплатная, у каждой версии свой ИД и свой функционал.

Допустим, мне надо внести изменение в 5-7 классов, дополнить их чем-то и в той и другой версии.

Как лучше всего и удобнее это делать ?

п.с. сейчас я пишу в одной версии, потом копирую ручками в другую.

Comment: Может быть полезно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/223972/182771

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Используйте Flavors.

Рецепт для Android Studio:

1. Открываете File-Project Structure-Flavors. Там уже будет defaultConfig. Создаете два flavor'а: paid и free. Указываете для каждого из них свой ApplicationId. Остальные данные указывать не обязательно, они будут браться из defaultConfig'а (возможно могут отличаться signing config, тогда его тоже указать, а может и нет, зависит от вашего проекта).
2. Теперь для каждого из flavor'а вы можете создать свои классы и ресурсы, они будут объединяться с имеющимся кодом (поверх). Файлы эти будут лежать рядом с main в директории src. Например:

   ```
   myproject
       app
           src
               main
                   java
                   res
                   assets
                   ...
               paid
                   java
                   res
                   ...
               free
                   res
                   ...
   ```

   2.1. Сама структура директорий не создается, придется это делать вручную. Хотя для ресурсов, например, можно выбрать sourceSet (по дефолту там main, но можно выбрать любой нужный) и тут уже структура и файлы (если надо) создадутся.
3. Открываете слева внизу в студии Build Variants и выбираете там нужный вам вариант запуска. Например, Module: app -> Build Variant: paidDebug. Переключаетесь на freeDebug, студия сама все пересоберет.
4. Профит.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Configuring Gradle Builds](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)
- [An Android Studio Gradle Build Variants Example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example)

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Когда дело доходит до повторного использования кода, очень удобно разбивать проект на несколько независимых **модулей**. Тогда, у вас фактически будет два уникальных приложения, использующих одни и те же библиотеки.

Разбиение на компоненты можно реализовать, например, на основе системы контроля версий (например [Git](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)). При этом, у вас получится три (или больше), репозитория, в которых будут храниться код платного и бесплатного приложений, а так же общих библиотек. Связь между репозиториями можно осуществлять (если речь идет о Git) через [подмодули](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).

При обновлении общих классов вы меняете их исходные код, отправляете изменения в репозиторий, обновляете зависимости в приложениях и прересобираете их, не занимаясь ручным копированием/вставкой кода.

Comment: Это, безусловно, работающий способ, но все же намного удобнее и правильнее пользоваться специализированным механизмом Flavors, который предназначен для решения именно таких задач (разделене кода на общюю и индивидуальную части). Он гораздо более гибкий и удобный в данной задаче.

Comment: @pavlofff, вы правы, но на мой взгляд, чем больше альтернативных путей решения проблемы, тем лучше :)

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего это реализовать через build.gradle в Android Studio. Почитайте про [productFlavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide). Добавьте следующие строки в build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    lite {
        packageName = 'com.project.test.app'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
    pro {
        packageName = 'com.project.testpro.app'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
}
```

В этом примере я добавил два типа приложения: lite-версию и pro-версию. Каждая версия имеет свой versionCode и versionName (для публикации в Google Play).

А в коде можно задать раздельную логику, проверяя переменную BuildConfig.FLAVOR:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "lite") {
   // код отображения рекламы или прочие ограничения функционала          
}
```

Для запуска и тестирования различных вариантов логики приложения на устройстве просто поменяйте тип запускаемого приложения на вкладке "Build Variants" в Android Studio. Список Build Variants автоматически сгенерируется исходя из указанных в build.gradle вариантов productFlavors:

[image]

Comment: `if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "lite") {` - подозрительно напоминает проверку в рантайме. Когда выполняется эта проверка?

Comment: Спасибо за столь детальный ответ!

Comment: @Qwertiy хм.. а что в этом плохого?

Comment: @Qwertiy Непосредственном в коде. Например, на какой-то activity необходимо показывать блок рекламы. Или в меню не отображать часть пунктов. Безусловно, если структрура кода версий значительно отличается, то вариант, который предложил Yura Ivanov в пунтке 2 с разбивкой директорий подойдет лучше.

Comment: @researcher 1. Накладные расходы при исполнении. 2. Пользователю отдаётся полная версия. Он (теоретически) может декомпилировать код: либо в своих целях, либо ради переопределения этой проверки и получения полной версии. 3. Вероятно, увеличение размера программы, поскольку она содержит обе версии. // По идее, всё это должно решаться не рантаймовыми проверками, а условной компиляцией, т. е. вместо `if (...)` использовать директивы `#if ...` или их аналоги для языка, которым ты пользуешься. Кстати, вот [интересная статья по теме](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6748867#p6748867).