# Размещение двух вариантов приложения в google play

Tags: android, google-play

Нужно разместить два приложения в google play, одно и то же приложение, только одно с бесплатным функционалом, другое с платным, и вопрос следующий:

Как я понимаю, нужно будет для второго создавать новый проект и копировать туда весь код. Или можно просто поправить код и выложить два с одним названием пакета? Но как тогда будут происходить обновления? и отпечаток же будет одинаков.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480999/ - не то, что вы хотите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете просто через рефакторинг сменить пакет приложению, скомпилировать апк и вернуть старый пакет.

Comment: Несколько костыльный способ какой то :). Есть специальный механизм в IDE - Flavors, который специально предназначен для таких задач. Позволяет одновременно работать над двумя (несколькими) версиями приложения (например, платной и бесплатной), совмещать одинаковый код и подготавливает уникальные приложения для размещения на Play Market (в том числе и с разными подписями, если требуется).

Comment: @pavlofff, ну да... Но я так раньше делал) По ссылке на дубль, вроде, как раз вами описываемый вариант)