# Тестовое и боевое приложение на одном устройстве

Tags: java, android, тестирование, package

Добрый день всем!
Есть развивающийся проект на android, java, eclipse. Меняя значение одной переменной можно собрать его как тестовое или как боевое. Там разные сервера, дополнительные логи, отключение каких-то проверок, подстановка тестовых данных и т. д.
Возникла необходимость установки и тестового и боевого на одно устройство, устройств таких чуть больше, чем несколько и может парк меняться. Не хочется какими-то внешними воздействиями переключать приложение из одного режима в другой, а хочется с МИНИМАЛЬНЫМИ телодвижения собирать оба варианта и ОБА устанавливать на одно устройство.
   У кого есть какие мысли? Типа чтобы package name менялось ВЕЗДЕ в зависимости от типа сборки.

Comment: [Используйте flavors](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480999/). Универсальный механизм.

Comment: У меня Eclipse.

Comment: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates.

Comment: нет, спасибо, она думает медленее чем я.

Comment: Ну, у вашего развивающегося проекта еще есть время передумать. Последний релиз ADT - август 2015, ужс.

Comment: И что тут ужасного? Сишные 32-битные проекты я делаю в шестой студии 1998 года выпуска и пока проблем нет.

Comment: Вы можете править build.gradle руками (или вы еще на Ant'е?), в ответе в моей ссылке есть статьи о том как это сделать. С 98 года туллинг улучшился и продолжает улучшаться, хотя работать можно и в блокноте.

Answer (score 0):

Лично в своих проектах я делаю dev панель, с доступом через шторку, висит вечное уведомление по клику, которому осуществляется переход на activity с различными настройками, которые можно динамически менять.
К примеру есть возможность поменять сервер. Увеличивать таймауты соединений и т.д. что душе угодно.
Все в одном приложении. Дев панель доступна при debug сборке